# In R, how do I count the number of data points on a scatter plot within a cell of custom dimensions?

Tags: r

Let's just say I have the following scatterplot:

```r
set.seed(665544)
n <- 100
x <- cbind(
  x=runif(10, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, sd=0.4),
  y=runif(10, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, sd=0.4)
)
plot(x)
```

[image]

I want to **divide this scatterplot into square cells of a specified size and then count how many points fall into each unique cell.** This will essentially give me the local density value of that cell. What is the best way of doing this? Is there an R package that can help? Perhaps a 2D histogram method like in Matlab?

---

Quick clarifications:

1.) I'd like the function/method to take the following 3 arguments: dimensions of total area, dimensions of cell (OR number of cells), and the data. It would then perhaps output a matrix where each value corresponds to a cell's point count.

2.) Q: Why do you want to use this method to determine local density? Isn't this much easier:

```r
library(dbscan)
pointdensity(x, eps = .1, type = "frequency")
```

A: This method calculates the local density around each point. Though easy, this definition of local density then makes it very difficult (optimization algorithms necessary) to assign new data in a way that it matches the local density distribution of the original data set.

Comment: For counts `gplot::hist2d`, for plotting `ggplot2::geom_bin2d`. Or the base R way without addiational packages: Use `cut` for each dimension and `table` the results.